# Exception : The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728896/the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-different-thread-owns-it)

I am making a Login Form in My WPF Project (WPF with C#)

I have one main form whose name is `Window1`. When I start the app a Login Dialog Form is first shown with `Username` and `Password` fields. If `Username` and `Password` are correct, then show `MainWindow1`.

My `Window1` has one `ListBox` which is to be filled.

When the app succeed in login, it has to add Item to `ListBox` control in `Window1`.
But An Exception is shown.

**Exception :**

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

I don't know what happen to my `ListBox` control?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use MethodInvoker

```
listBox.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => listBox.Items.Add(item)));
```

Comment: Error Invoke method, I don't how to fix it?

Comment: Tell me what error you are getting fully and which line.