# The calling thread cannot access the object because a different thread owns it

Tags: c#, wpf, busyindicator

In my project I have a `busyindicator` and I'm using `ListObject` in `FirstMethod` and `SecondMethod`.

The program gives the following error:

> The calling thread cannot access the object because a different thread owns it

I am using the following code:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ListObjectProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("ListObject", typeof(ObservableCollection<FileViewModel>), typeof(MyObjectViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(ChangeCallback));

public ObservableCollection<FileViewModel> ListObject
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<FileViewModel>)GetValue(ListObjectProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ListObjectProperty, value); }
}

private void SelectedPath()
{
    NavigatePage(new Page2());              
    FirstMethod();
}


private void FilesCase()
{
    var t = new Task(() => this.ThreadFilesCase());

    t.ContinueWith(
        (o) =>
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                IsBusy = false; NavigatePage(new Page3());
            }));
        });

    IsBusy = true;    
    t.Start();
}

private void ThreadFilesCase()
{
       SecondMethod();      
}
```

Comment: Have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764747/exception-the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-different-thr
You'll likely need to set up a delegate and invoke.

Comment: Is there anything in `SecondMethod` that is accessing a `UIElement`

Comment: This is most likely due multithreading. I answered anyway, helping you with your specific problem. Try reading some stuff on multi threading and updating ui controls from another thread.

Comment: "… You'll likely need to set up a delegate and invoke" - can you write any example

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`, withtin the `ContinueWith` delegate. Meaning it's invoking on the backgroundworker thread. Use the Dispatcher obtained from the ui control. Or use the `SynchronizationContext` that is used when the ui controls are (being) created.

Example: `myBusyIndicator.Dispatcher.Invoke(...)`, instead off `Dispatcher.Invoke(...)`

Comment: I don't use myBusyIndicator, in my xaml - <extToolkit:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}" BusyContent="Wait please...">

Comment: Then give your indicator a Name so you can access it in the code behind

Comment: It's navigation page project with own viewModel for each page. I can't resolve indicator Name in MyViewModel