# WPF: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I know there are similar questions like [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732709/the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-different-thread-owns-it?noredirect=1&lq=1) And [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728896/the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-different-thread-owns-it?noredirect=1&lq=1), I looked them all, but they seems not work for me.

I have a thread:

```
private void Sample()
{
      Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Sample_Thread));
      t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
      t.Start();
}
```

In the Sample_Thread, I previously called `MessageBox` which works fine.

```
private void Sample_Thread()
{
     try{ ... }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
          MessageBox.Show("SampleText");
     }
}
```

Now I try to call `ModernDialog` instead of `MessageBox`, it gives me error `'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'`
 so I change my code to this:

```
private void Sample_Thread()
{
     try{ ... }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                ModernDialog.ShowMessage("SampleText");
            });
     }
}
```

But this still got that same error, how should I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: There are a lot of duplicates and all of them work. Just *DON'T* try to modify the UI from another thread. Displaying a message box *is* a UI operation. Use `async/await` and tasks and you won't need Invoke. There's no reason to use raw threads either, use `Task.Run`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a lot of duplicates, all of which work and all of which say the same thing: You can't modify the UI from another thread. Displaying a messagebox *does* modify the UI. This restriction applies to all versions of Windows going back at least to Windows 95 *and* other OSs like Linux.

You don't need `Invoke` to update the UI or raw threads to perform anything in the background either. .NET allows you to execute work in the background with `Task.Run`, await its result and handle any exceptions. The only thing you need to write is :

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
...
}

private async void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(someMethod);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        ModernDialog.ShowMessage(e.ToString());
     }
}
```

If you want to update the UI while processing in the background, eg to display progress, you can use the `IProgress< T>` as [explained here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/), to report using any type as a message, eg int, string or a full class :

```
private void SomeMethod(IProgress<string> progress)
{
   foreach(...)
   {
       progress.Report("foo");
       ....
   }
}

private async void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var progressIndicator = new Progress<string>(reportProgressMethod);
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(()=>someMethod(progressIndicator());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        ModernDialog.ShowMessage(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

`async void` should only be used for event handlers. In all other cases, the method signature of an asynchronous method that doesn't return a result should be `async Task`

Comment: If I want to display the progress of the thread by the control I already have e.g. TextBlock. I declare this `ReportProgress(int value, string hint){ TextBlock1.Text = value; TextBlock.Text2.Text = hint;}`. How should I asynchronously this UI?